# Exporting multiple .nsf mailboxes to local drive at the same time from Domino Server

Tags: server, copy, export, lotus-domino

There is an option to select one file, Copy Database, and specify the location on the local machine. However as soon as I select more than one, the Copy Database option is greyed out. I have ~500 mailboxes to export, totalling 2TB of space.

I have full admin access, I can use the Domino console. I can't find any info at all anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have remote login to the server, you can share a local folder and copy that way. But you'll need to shut down the Domino server while doing that in order to make sure the files are closed. If you can't/don't want to do that, then your option is to write a short piece of LotusScritp that uses [NotesDatabase.CreateCopy](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/12.0.0/basic/H_CREATECOPY_METHOD.html) to copy the files. You may want to use the [NotesDbDirectory](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDBDIRECTORY_CLASS.html) class in order locate the specific files, but it wouldn't be necessary if you already have a list of filepaths for the databases that you want to copy.

Comment: Thank you for some light on this! Unfortunately the first method I don't know how to do, I know nothing about these systems. And as for the second - I have an IBM Designer application that allows me to write LotusScript but I don't even know how to run it... Anyway this looks like a GUI creating tool. Is there something other that people use just to run short scripts?

Comment: Never mind, got it. I used Designer to create a small GUI app and to call my code on click.

Answer (score 1):

I used Richard's suggestion. The code I wrote to copy a mailbox:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim localDb As NotesDatabase
Dim sourcePath As String
Dim targetPath As String
Dim server As String

server = "<Server>"
sourcePath = "mail/<mailbox.nsf>"
targetPath = "C:\Temp\mailbox_data\<mailbox.nsf>"

Set db = session.GetDatabase(server, sourcePath)
Set localDb = db.CreateReplica("", targetPath)
Call db.Close
```